# Android canvas line strokeCap round larger than simple line

Tags: android, canvas, kotlin, paint, rounded-corners

I am trying to draw a rounded line of a specific width on my imageView Bitmap.

So I drew a simple line with `paintLine.strokeCap = Paint.Cap.ROUND` and without this option.

Here is the result :

[image: Deferences between two type of lines]

The first one is rounded and you can see it's larger than the bottom one.

Here is the code I use.

```
    val paintLine = Paint()
    paintLine.color = Color.WHITE
    paintLine.style = Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE
    paintLine.strokeWidth = 40.0f
    paintLine.strokeCap = Paint.Cap.ROUND

    val workingBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap)
    val mutableBitmap = workingBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true)

    val drawingBitmapCanvas = Canvas(mutableBitmap)

    drawingBitmapCanvas.apply {
        drawLine(300, 300, 400, 300, paintLine)
    }
```

**I would like to know if there is a way to keep the same width with rounded line ?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This just requires a little bit of math on your part. The rounded stroke caps that are added to the line have a width/length that is equal to half the stroke of the paint.

Here is my code:

```
Paint linePaint =  new Paint();
Paint noCaplinePaint =  new Paint();

public void init(){
    linePaint.setColor(this.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
    linePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    linePaint.setStrokeWidth(40f);
    linePaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

    noCaplinePaint.setColor(this.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
    noCaplinePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    noCaplinePaint.setStrokeWidth(40f);
}
```

And then in `onDraw`:

```
canvas.drawLine(50f, 40f, 300f, 40f, noCaplinePaint);
canvas.drawLine(70f, 81f, 280f, 81f, linePaint);
```

Produces these lines:

[image: Produced Lines]

So, to review, the size of a rounded line cap can be calculated like this:

`additionalLengthFromRoundCap = lineStrokeWidth/2`

and this cap will be added to both ends of the line, so the line will be `strokeWidth` units longer than drawn.

Comment: Great answer, thanks ! The points (startX, startY) and (endX, endY) are not always in the same order, so I just had to check if (endX, endY) > (startX, startY) and reverse them, and it work every time !